# How to create checkbox inside the form group selection HTML Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Currently, I have 200+ countries list in my database. I want to create a checkbox for the countries selection. Even I already put the html type as a checkbox, the checkbox still doesn't exist in my selection form. How to create checkbox actually?

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control"  name="country_id[]" multiple  size="10" style="height: 100%;">
                        @foreach ($countries as $item)
                            <option value="{{$item->id}}" selected>{{$item->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: This is current output]

Comment: You can't as it's not possible to put any additional HTML inside an `option` element. If you need to do this you'll need to re-create the `select` using plain HTML and JS. There are libraries which can do this for you, such as Chosen and Select2

Comment: Where have you "put the html type as a checkbox"? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Preselecting every element is not really useful, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `<input type="checkbox">`? `<select>` is a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot place checkbox inside select element but you can get the same functionality by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also you can use [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plugin.